# Tag score not matching combined score of tag answers

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, tags

I just started using PPCG and I'm off to a good start, almost 400 rep in a week.

My best tag is [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf). But while I was looking at my profile, I saw a bit of a problem.
[image]
My score for [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is 19, but the score of a few of my [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) answers adds up to over 19.

What's going on?

Comment: I blame caching.

Comment: [* Advice may be incorrect do to caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: @programmer5000 [* Grammar may be incorrect due to autocorrect](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com/)

Comment: +1 for the hand drawn circles!

Comment: @MartinEnder I don't think so, it's higher now but still about 15 less than it should be.

Comment: @MDXF You got 21 upvotes on code golf answers today. I still blame caching (I think these tag totals are only updated once per day).

Comment: @MartinEnder And I thank you for those 21 upvotes. Great challenge :D